# AWS SES send mail error SMTP Error: Could not authenticate after sending about 1000 mails

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, bulk

I'm the regular user for AWS SES, and I got the quota for 50K per days, and 28 mail per seconds,
   I usually send transactional mail, about 1000 per day. It works fine.
   But, I want to send some bulk promotion mail to my clients this time.
   It show "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" frequently after I send about 1000~ mails.
   But, some of them are still sent correctly. I got "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" for about 30%~50% email sending.
   I use phpMailer and send mail in a for loop and it takes about 3 seconds for sending one mail.
   It seems I'm not over the quota or something I need to take care?

Comment: Is it possible you've been blacklisted and/or your credentials revoked after sending so many emails? Seems like a question for your email provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an error you are getting today? I had similar issues earlier today on much lower volumnes and according to the aws status page, they had some issues today:

http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Thank you for your information, I didn't think AWS SES went wrong....I use SES for about 2 months, and send about 200~1000 mails every day, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`SMTP Error: Could not authenticate` doesn't sound like a *real* error message to me.  In fact, I'm certain it isn't, because a *real* error message in SMTP always has a 3-digit code.

> Every command MUST generate exactly one reply.
>
> An SMTP reply consists of a three digit number (transmitted as three
>      numeric characters) followed by some text unless specified otherwise
>      in this document.  The number is for use by automata to determine
>      what state to enter next; the text is for the human user.  The three
>      digits contain enough encoded information that the SMTP client need
>      not examine the text and may either discard it or pass it on to the
>      user, as appropriate.
>
> <sup>— http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt</sup>

It sounds like whatever tool you're using for the SMTP connection is trying to be "helpful" and showing you a "friendly" error message, and is discarding the useful part in exchange for simply "Could not authenticate."

Find a way to turn on some debugging in the SMTP library that you are using, so that you can  find out the *actual* error message that is occurring, and you then should have an obvious answer to your question.

Without that, it's guesswork.

It should be one of [these documented codes in SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html), each of which has a specific cause:

```
454 Throttling failure: Daily message quota exceeded.  
454 Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded. 
454 Temporary authentication failure                   
530 Authentication required.
535 Authentication Credentials Invalid
554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
```

Comment: I use PHPmailer , and it output the message. It seems fine now.